# How can I filter parts after they are inside of [ and ]?

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

Im trying to filter a .json file which I got from the dark sky api.
I have trouble to do the same thing with multiple apis which output .json files (spotify, reddit, lastfm and dark sky).
This is the whole .json file from : http://pastebin.com/rxqHBumk.
I can filter that file with the command: jq '.daily.data' till that state: http://pastebin.com/Mukz14rJ but I cant filter it further than that.

I would apriciate every help since Im stuck on this point.

Comment: What do you mean by 'filter'?

Comment: I want for example to get the value after "summary":

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add representative input and desired output *to the question itself* (no external links!), along with what you've tried (see [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I filter parts after they are inside of [ and ]?

There are basically two ways:

1. If you want to preserve the array, then pipe into: map(select(...))
2. Otherwise, pipe into .[] | select(...)

Answer (score 0):

jq can probably solve this.

To extract just the `.summary` values from each element of `.daily.data` with `[]`, use

```
.daily.data[].summary
```

Running this over the value from the specified pastebin returns

```
"Leichter Regen am Vormittag und Nacht."
"Leichter Regen am Vormittag."
"Den ganzen Tag lang überwiegend bewölkt."
"Leichter Regen von nachmittags bis abends."
"Den ganzen Tag lang stark bewölkt."
"Abends Nieselregen."
"Den ganzen Tag lang Regen."
"Leichter Regen am Vormittag und Abend."
```

To obtain a version with each element of `.daily.data` replaced with an object containing only the summary use the filter

```
 .daily.data[] |= {summary}
```

Running this over the value from the specified pastebin returns

```
{
  "latitude": 53,
  "longitude": 9,
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "offset": 1,
  "daily": {
    "summary": "Die ganze Woche leichter Regen mit einem Temperaturminimum von 7°C am Mittwoch.",
    "icon": "rain",
    "data": [
      {
        "summary": "Leichter Regen am Vormittag und Nacht."
      },
      {
        "summary": "Leichter Regen am Vormittag."
      },
      {
        "summary": "Den ganzen Tag lang überwiegend bewölkt."
      },
      {
        "summary": "Leichter Regen von nachmittags bis abends."
      },
      {
        "summary": "Den ganzen Tag lang stark bewölkt."
      },
      {
        "summary": "Abends Nieselregen."
      },
      {
        "summary": "Den ganzen Tag lang Regen."
      },
      {
        "summary": "Leichter Regen am Vormittag und Abend."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If something else is desired it can probably be accomplished with tweaking.

Answer (score -1):

I'm 99% sure I understand things correctly so here goes: I understand you want to take the lines that say "summary" in the second paste and extract the values.  I don't know json and I'm assuming your `jq` command formats the json data nicely, filling the line breaks and so forth.  Assuming there will only be one `summary` on a line, that the summary value never contains quoted double quotes, and the value will never cross a line break, you can accomplish what you want with the following:

```
egrep '^ *"summary":' json.txt | while IFS= read line; do expr match "$line" ' *"summary": "\(.*\)".*'; done
```

What this says to loop (`while`) over all lines in the file `json.txt` that contain a `summary` field at the beginning of the line (`^`) except for unlimited spaces (`*`) (`egrep '^ *"summary":' json.txt |`), reading (`read`) them into the variable `line` without losing whitespace (`IFS=`), and then extract (`expr match`) from that line (`"$line"`) the contents of the second quoted string (`' *"summary": "\(.*\)".*'`), where `\(` and `\)` isolate what you want to print out (move the quotes inside these delimiters if you want them included in the output).  `.*` means a string of any (zero or more) characters.  `|` means take the output of the left command and feed it to the input of the right command.

This is very simple.  I am assuming that there are json tools to do what you want to do but I don't know what they are.  They may be more complicated than this but if you are going to do a lot of json processing it may behoove you to find them and learn them.

Comment: You don't know JSON, you don't know what `jq` is, but you felt the need to chime in with an answer anyway?

Comment: @chepner, The question was tagged `bash` so I answered it with bash.  I was viewing all the new questions tagged "bash" and it came up, so I answered it with what I knew.